# Tree structure with drag and drop rows in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid for tree structure in a table.I'm providing drag and drop row functionality.I want to call a callback method on drag event.Because I want to adjust the hierarchy of the rows which is a column having number in it ex:1.1,1.2.1,...Can I do this.
The following is the code I wrote inside my html:

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#tree").tableDnD({scrollAmount:0}); 
jQuery("#tree").jqGrid({
url:'jsonSamplePots.json',
datatype: "json",
colNames: ["Task Id", "Task No.", "Task Name", "Priority", "Start Date", "End Date", "Task Type", "Link", "Link RelationShip", "Resources(Units)", "Reference"],

            colModel: [

                 {name:'id', index:'id', width: 30, hidden: true, key: true},
                {name:'no', width:80, sortable:false,editable:true},
                {name:'name', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true},
                {name:'priority', width:80, sortable:false,editable:true},
                {name:'sDate', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'eDate', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'type', width:120, sortable:false},
                {name:'link', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'rship', width:80, sortable:false},
                {name:'resources', width:300, sortable:false},
                {name:'ref', width:80, sortable:false},

            ],

rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: '#pcelltbl',
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"Tasks",
cellEdit:true,
treeGrid: true,

ExpandColumn:'name',
gridComplete: function() {
    //alert("gridcomplete");
    $("#_empty","#tree").addClass("nodrag nodrop");
    jQuery("#tree").tableDnDUpdate();
},
```

I'm using the following json data:

```
{
"total": "1",
"page": "1",
"records": "2",
"rows": [
       {"id": "1", "cell":  ["1",  "Super <b>Item</b>",     "300", "0", "",  "false", "true", "true"]},
       {"id": "2", "cell":  ["2",  "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>", "100", "1", "1", "false", "false", "true"]},
       {"id": "3", "cell":  ["3",  "Sub Item 1",     "50",  "2", "2", "true",  "true",  "true"]},
       {"id": "4", "cell":  ["4",  "Sub Item 2",     "25",  "2", "2", "false", "false", "true"]},
       {"id": "5", "cell":  ["5",  "Sub-sub Item 1", "25",  "3", "4", "true",  "true",  "true"]},
       {"id": "6", "cell":  ["6",  "Sub Item 3",     "25",  "2", "2", "true",  "true",  "true"]},
       {"id": "7", "cell":  ["7",  "<span style='background-color:LightGreen; color:Tomato'>Item 2</span>", "200", "1", "1", "false", "true", "true"]},
       {"id": "8", "cell":  ["8",  "Sub Item 1",     "100", "2", "7", "false", "false", "true"]},
       {"id": "9", "cell":  ["9",  "Sub-sub Item 1", "50",  "3", "8", "true",  "true",  "true"]},
       {"id": "10", "cell": ["10", "Sub-sub Item 2", "50",  "3", "8", "true",  "true",  "true"]},
       {"id": "11", "cell": ["11", "Sub Item 2",     "100", "2", "7", "true",  "true",  "true"]}
]
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for looking at this post:) Got it work...                                                                   jQuery("#tree").tableDnD({onDrop: function(table,row){//write your logic here}});

Comment: I read your post and tried to extend `sortableRows` working with TreeGrid. I don't have enough time to make it working till the end, but moving of nodes (still without its all children) works. See the preliminary demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree11_.htm).